# Cordova : How to detect that Facebook plugin has loaded?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing an iOS app with Cordova and I am using the Facebook-connect plugin for authentification.

My problem : sometimes the Facebook Plugin doesn't load early enough so the FB authentification doesn't go the native way, but through a kind of in-app browser popup.

Is there a way to detect that Fb plugin has finished loading ?

Thank you

Comment: let me know so I can assist you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use facebook phonegap plugin as your authentication.

Download and install into your cordova project.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Then make sure you have this script in your project.

```
cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js
facebook-js-sdk.js
```

After that, paste this code into your main script

```
if ((typeof cordova == 'undefined') && (typeof Cordova == 'undefined')) alert('Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly');
if (typeof CDV == 'undefined') alert('CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly');
if (typeof FB == 'undefined') alert('FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.');
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.login event');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.logout event');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.sessionChange event');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.statusChange event');
});

function getSession() {
    alert("session: " + JSON.stringify(FB.getSession()));
}

function getLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            alert('logged in');
        } else {
            alert('not logged in');
        }
    });
}
var friendIDs = [];
var fdata;

function logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        alert('logged out');
        window.location.replace("#login");
    });
}

function login() {
    FB.login(

    function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            alert('logged in');
            FB.api('/me', function(me) {
                if (me.id) {
                                    localStorage.id = me.id;
                    localStorage.email = me.email;
                    localStorage.name = me.name;
                    window.location.replace("#home");
                }
                else {
                    alert('No Internet Connection. Click OK to exit app');
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('not logged in');
        }
    }, {
        scope: "email"
    });
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    try {
        //alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
        FB.init({
            appId: "appid",
            nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
            useCachedDialogs: false
        });
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}, false);
```

use `login()` to login . Enjoy!!

Comment: I probably should have been clearer in the description of my problem. I am actually using the plugin. Most of the times it works well. But sometimes it goes through a browser popup.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an entry in the log, if the plugin fails to load while testing the app.

Also looks like you are using facebook API, phonegap other native plugins always load after the recommended plugins offered in [here.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%0AGuide)

Also it loads as per the order you mentioned in the XML file,

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

and

```
<plugin name="" value="" />
```

As developers clearly knows debugging in Phonegap is difficult than pushing a tanker.

Hope the following invoking method helps,

1. Add the reference of your plugin to your `index.html`
2. After the `onDeviceReady()` function, add the JavaScript for invoking the native plugin and handling the plugin results.
3. Add JavaScript functions named `callNativePlugin`, `nativePluginResultHandler`, `andnativePluginErrorHandler`

as shown below,

```
function callYourPlugin( returnSuccess ) { 
    YourPlugin.callNativeFunction( YourPluginResultHandler, YourPluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess ); 
} 
function YourPluginResultHandler (result) { 
   alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result ); 
} 
function YourPluginErrorHandler (error) { 
   alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error ); 
}
```

Finally add buttons to invoke your plugins as follows,

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()"> 
     <h1>Hey, it's Cordova!</h1> 
      <button onclick="callYourPlugin('success');">Click to invoke the Native Plugin with an SUCCESS!</button> 
      <button onclick="callYourPlugin('error');">Click to invoke the Native Plugin with an ERROR!</button> 
</body>
```

I feel this method as easy to invoke any plugins, also you can checkout this [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html) for more.